# component one c1upload does fire in callback event so does not support text box ,label values

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, componentone

```
protected void C1Upload2_ValidatingFile(object sender, C1.Web.Wijmo.Controls.C1Upload.ValidateFileEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var s = e.UploadedFile.GetStream();
        byte[] imgbyte = new byte[s.Length];
        s.Read(imgbyte, 0, Convert.ToInt32(s.Length));
        string type = e.UploadedFile.Extension;
        if (e.IsValid)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_pdm_shopping_upload", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sample", SqlDbType.Char, 10));
            SqlParameter contentparameter = null;
            contentparameter = (new SqlParameter("@image", SqlDbType.Image));
            contentparameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(contentparameter);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@type", SqlDbType.Char, 10));
            cmd.Parameters["@sample"].Value = txt_code.Text;
            cmd.Parameters["@image"].Value = imgbyte;
            cmd.Parameters["@type"].Value = "INV";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            e.IsValid = false;
            s.Close();
            e.UploadedFile.Delete();
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMsg.Visible = true;
            this.ErrorMsg.Text = e.UploadedFile.FileName + Environment.NewLine;
        }

    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you've left the details of your *actual question* out (this is all code).  Could you [edit] in a description of the problem you're having?

Comment: does not get input value in standard controls(text box,label,radio button,etc...)

Comment: Where are you calling this function from, and where are `con` and `cmd` defined?  Also, why are you calling `Convert.ToInt(s.Length)`?  s.Length should already be an int, so there's no need to convert.

Comment: ok problem is does not get(textbox,label,radio button) value in c1upload validating file

Comment: i added connection, command in page load function above...

Comment: any one find the solution ...